# ConveterParameter as integer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I have some radio buttons which each represent a numeric (integer) value. They are bound to a numeric property in the view model and they use a converter to convert the integer value to a boolean. The problem is, that the Converter parameter appears to be parsed as a string, so my converter returns false, even when I have to identical numbers.

My best bet would be to specify that the `ConverterParameter` is an integer, but how do I do that?

**RadioButton XAML:**

```
<RadioButton Content="1" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedValue, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" />
```

**Binding property in view model:**

```
// The SetProperty method handles INotifyProperyChanged
private int _selectedValue;
public int SelectedValue
{
    get { return _selectedValue; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _selectedValue, value); }
}
```

**My converter:**

```
public class MyConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your Parameter and Value to a suitable format like double/integer first! Something like this

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToInt32(value) == System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter);
    }
```

Comment: Why to `double`, when I want it to be integers?

Comment: you can use interger as well doesnt really matter but double can handle more numbers (updated answer)

Comment: Okay. One more thing. Aren't both sides of the `==` in your code identical? Or do I fail to see something?

Comment: ups fixed that :)

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. I was so focused on figuring out how to convert in `XAML` that I forgot that it could be done in the converter :-). I will accept your answer in a few minutes (StackOverflow timer).

Comment: Glad i could help! Converters can be a bit confusing sometimes...espacially with parameters or multibinding but you get used to it pretty quickly